# Play! Error messages not getting displayed on UI

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am able to print the error messages in the console but unable to display the error messages in the UI.

This is the action code:

```
public static void welcome(User user){
    validation.required("User Name",user.name).message("validation.message.em");
    validation.required("Password",user.password).message("validation.message.em");
    if(validation.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Validation errors found!!!");
        for(Error error:validation.errors())
            System.out.println(error.message());
        params.flash(); // add http parameters to the flash scope
        validation.keep(); // keep the errors for the next request
        login();
    }
```

This is the UI html code:

```
#{form @Application.welcome(), method:'get', id:'loginForm' }
        <table>
            <tr style="height: 100px">
                <td colspan="2"><h1>
                        <b>Login</b>
                    </h1></td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                #{field 'user.name'}
                    <td> &{field.name} </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}" class="${field.errorClass}">
                    <span class="error">${field.error}</span>
                #{/field}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                #{field 'user.password'}
                    <td> &{field.name} </td>
                    <td><input type="password" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}" class="${field.errorClass}">
                    <span class="error">${field.error}</span>
                #{/field}                   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    #{/form}
```

This is the messages conf entry:

```
user.name=User Name
user.password=Password
validation.message.em=%s is required.
```

Please let me know what am I missing :(

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

change the code as;

```
validation.required("user.name",user.name).message("validation.message.em");
validation.required("user.password",user.password).message("validation.message.em");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the validation works. But again, I am not able to retain the user-input values. e.g. if I input only for username and click the login button, then the password required is getting displayed and the input value for username is getting cleared. I want to retain the username value...Please let me know about this. Thanks,

Comment: @WhoAmI , i tried your code, it is working. Also username value is being set.